# How to handle routing error Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

I am wondering what would be the best practise and approach to handle routing error for specific controller?

In my case i have 2 resources

```
resources :user
resources :special_user
```

I want that everything that throws routing error redirects back to that resources index, for example:

request to `mydomain.com/users/blahblah`, will redirect to `mydomain.com/users`

and same for special user `mydomain.com/special_users/blahblah` will redirect back to `mydomain.com/special_users`

What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: I think that what you need to do isn't to handle routing errors as such, but to allow for the "random" case in your routes file.  Always better to anticipate and handle the unexpected before it actually causes an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
resources :users do
  # if you need to add new routes, add them before the catch all
  get  '*a', to: redirect('/users')
end
resources :special_users do
  # if you need to add new routes, add them before the catch all
  get  '*a', to: redirect('/special_users')
end
```

---

An alternative is to do:

```
resources :special_users do
  # if you need to add new routes, add them before the catch all
  get  '*a', action: :catch_all
end
```

and in your special_users controller, you defined the action:

```
def catch_all
  # maybe set some flash message
  redirect_to special_users_path
end
```

---

Thanks to @JiříPospíšil 's comment I realize you may have one more thing to check.

In your show actions (for users for instance):

```
def  show
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if @user
    # usual stuff here
  else 
    # flash message?
    redirect_to users_path
  end
end
```

(I assumed you forgot to pluralize your resources)

Comment: Is this really going to help the OP with `request to mydomain.com/users/blahblah, will redirect to mydomain.com/users`? From the point of the router, a request to `users/blahblah` is perfectly valid, it's a request to `UsersController#show` with `id = blahblah`. The route `get  '*a', to: redirect('/users')` will only get matched if there's a constraint violation (e.g. requesting `/users/bla/bla`). What am I missing?